# AngularJs filter function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

Hey guys i am working on `angularjs` project and need some help.

Can you explain me how to use this html code in `javascript` function.

HTML

```
{{((songs | filter:albumf | filter:searchFilter).length/10) | roundup}} //  98
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 app.filter('roundup', function () {
    return function (value) {
        return Math.ceil(value);
    };
})


$filter('filter')(songs, function() {
  return ;
});
```

Comment: use filter functions somewhere in `.controller`

Comment: Actually i am very new to this! So can you help me build that

Comment: sure. Show me the  code of the filter functions

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var x = $filter('filter')(songs, $scope.albumf)(songs, $scope. searchFilter).length/10;

$scope.final = $filter('roundup')(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by my self.

I just did something like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="x in filterLength = (songs | filter:searchFilter| filter:albumFilter)"></span>
```

Than i used `$scope.x` in in javascript wherever i needed some thing like this.

```
    $scope.foo = function() {
      if((Match.ceil($scope.x.length)) == 0) {
        ...
      } else {
        ...
      }
    }
```